# Как после нажатия Inline кнопки кинуть invoice? aiogram | python

Tags: python, aiogram

Мне нужно, чтобы после нажатия на Inline кнопку пользователю приходило сообщение с invoice об оплате. Прошу помочь, буду очень признателен!

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data == '500')
async def process_callback_button1(call):
    tg_id = call.message.chat.id
    await bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
    await bot.send_invoice(chat_id=tg_id,
                           title='Подписка на Бота',
                           description='(Тест!!!)',
                           provider_token=config.KASSA,
                           currency='rub',
                           photo_url='photo',
                           photo_width=416,
                           photo_height=234,
                           photo_size=416,
                           is_flexible=False,
                           prices=[PRICE1],
                           start_parameter='one_mount_subscribe',
                           payload='test_invioce_pyaload')
```

Answer (score 0):

reply_markup укажи в send_invoice

Там создай inline клавиатуру, и кнопку оплаты сделай pay=True, например:
InlineKeyboardButton(text="Оплатить", pay=True)